# Change icons of application in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, icons

I installed a new icon set (numix), however not all icons were changed (e.g. the software manager). How can I manually change icons?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of finding the location of the icon for an application is to add it to the panel (right click > add to panel) and then right click on the newly added icon to edit it. By clicking on the icon in "Launcher Properties" you'll get its location. 
For instance `mintInstall` is found in `/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintInstall/icon.svg`

Having this you can then replace the icon with you own file and you can remove the application from the panel again.

Answer (score 3):

On newer versions of Linux Mint (tested on 19.1) the accepted solution doesn't work. You have to go to `/usr/share/applications` with elevated privileges (command: `sudo nemo`) and then modify the icon from there (Right click on icon you want to change -> properties -> click on the icon in upper left of dialog).

Answer (score 1):

Click on the rocket icon in the Application Launcher and you can upload an icon.

Answer (score 1):

In the file right click and choose `properties` Then, in the top left side you should see the actual icon, left click and in the new window choose the image.

Comment: Right-click the launcher, choose `Properties`, then choose `Applications`, then select the desired icon.

Answer (score 0):

Right click any item in Linux and under properties change emblem this works for most files.

Comment: Unfortunately, Cinnamon isn't very strong exactly in this...